# Is it possible to run puma and passenger in a same nginx server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger, puma

We have a production machine runs on Nginx + phusion passenger. Passenger is pointing to ruby verions 2.3. Want to deploy another application into the same server in which we require, ruby version 2.4+.

I believe, we cannot use that with the passenger any more as it is already pointing to a ruby version. So thinking to use puma for the other app with ruby version 2.4.

Is it possible to run puma and passenger in a same nginx server ?

Comment: Yes. Next, I recommend you try it and if you fail to make it work then come back here and ask a new question explaining what you've tried and where you're stuck.